# Bookshelf.js belongsToMany query with wrong column

Tags: javascript, mysql, bookshelf.js

I'm fighting hard with relations inside my bookshelf model. What I'm trying to do is to create schema which contains 4 tables:

- users
- roles
- privileges
- privileges_roles

With relations between them like this:

**users** manyTOone **roles** manyTOone **privileges_roles** oneTOmany **privileges**

I've easily achieved relations between privileges and roles with:

**Privileges**

```
class Privileges {
    constructor() {
        this.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
            tableName: 'privileges',
            roles: function () {
                return this.belongsToMany(Roles.model).through(PrivilegeRole.model);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

**Roles**

```
class Roles {
    constructor() {
        this.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
          tableName: 'roles',
          privileges: function() {
              return this.belongsToMany(Privileges.model).through(PrivilegeRole.model);
          },
          users: function() {
              return this.hasMany(Users.model);
          }
        });
    };
}
```

**PrivilegeRole**

```
class PrivilegeRole {
    constructor() {
        this.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
          tableName: 'privileges_roles',
          role: function() {
              return this.belongsTo(Roles.model);
          },
          privileges: function() {
              return this.belongsTo(Privileges.model);
          }
        });
    };
}
```

Those works really fine. Unfortunately when I'm trying to fetch **Privileges** from **User** model it keep inserting **id** instead of **role_id** to query.

```
class Users {
    constructor() {
        this.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
            tableName: 'users',
            role: function () {
                return this.belongsTo(Role.model);
            },
            privileges: function () {
                // return this.belongsToMany(Privileges.model).through(PrivilegeRole.model);
                return this.belongsToMany(Privileges.model, 'privileges_roles', 'role_id', 'privilege_id', 'role_id');
            }
        });
    };
}
```

So at the end whatever I do, bookshelf is creating query like this:

> select `privileges`.*, `privileges_roles`.`id` as `_pivot_id`,
>   `privileges_roles`.`role_id` as `_pivot_role_id`,
>   `privileges_roles`.`privilege_id` as `_pivot_privilege_id` from
>   `privileges` inner join `privileges_roles` on
>   `privileges_roles`.`privilege_id` = `privileges`.`id` where
>   `privileges_roles`.`role_id` in (1)

Instead of `role_id` in (3) like it's in a record fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I've finally found a solution. Instead of previously used:

```
privileges: function () {
                return this.belongsToMany(Privileges.model, 'privileges_roles', 'role_id', 'privilege_id', 'role_id');
            }
```

I had to simply use:

```
privileges: function () {
                return this.belongsToMany(Privileges.model).through(PrivilegeRole.model, 'role_id', 'privilege_id', 'role_id');
            }
```